# Declare a local variable in named calculation expression

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2017, calculated-field

I would like to create a named calculation field for age, and I want to declare a local variable inside an expression like the following, but it doesn't not work :

```
DECLARE
@age INT;

@age=DateDiff("yyyy",DATE_NAIS,getdate());

CASE WHEN @age<=10 THEN  1
WHEN @age>10 AND @age<=20 THEN 2
WHEN @age>20 AND @age<=35 THEN 3
ELSE 4
END
```

Comment: Just use `DateDiff("yyyy",DATE_NAIS,getdate())` in place of the variable.

Comment: Side note, `DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, GETDATE())` does not return the **age** of a person, it return the age they will turn this year. `DATEDIFF(year, '20001231',GETDATE())`would return 19, despite the fact that the person has over 10 months till their 19th birthday.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's just to prepare data, I will adjust a good function for the age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you cannot DECLARE a variable in the context of an expression in a SELECT, like you are trying to do.

You have a few different options, one of which digital.aaron gave in his comments.

Another is to create it as an artificial column in a CTE, and then select from the CTE instead of the table:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, DateDiff("yyyy",DATE_NAIS,getdate()) AS age FROM MyTable)
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN age<=10 THEN  1
  WHEN age>10 AND age<=20 THEN 2
  WHEN age>20 AND age<=35 THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END AS SomeColumn
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged with SSAS, so I'm guessing you're doing this in a cube?  The following DAX formula will work as a calculated column in your model for what was described in your post.  As stated in the comments `DATEDIFF` alone will only return the difference between the current year and the year the person was born, which is why `YEARFRAC` is used to obtain the fraction of a year, then this is rounded **down** to the nearest integer via the `INT` function.  For example, someone who is 50 years, 364 days old would be considered 50, not 51.  Since `TRUE()` is given as the first argument of the `SWITCH` function, this will evaluate each condition until a match is found.

```
PersonAge:= 
    var Age = INT(YEARFRAC(YourTable[DATE_NAIS], TODAY()))

RETURN

SWITCH
    (TRUE(), 
    Age < 10, 1,
AND(
    Age > 10, 
    Age <= 20), 2,
AND(
    Age > 20, 
    Age <= 35), 3,
    4)
```